# How to get the number of all possible poll paths?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a quiz that shows a question depending on the answer. The JSON file contains the id of the questions that are displayed when you select.The question object looks like this:

```js
const quiz = [
  {
    id: "1",
    question: "question1",
    answer1: {
      text: "answ1",
      nextQuestion: "2",
    },
    answer2: {
      text: "answ2",
      nextQuestion: "3",
    },
  },

  {
    id: "2",
    question: "question2",
    answer1: {
      text: "answ1",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
    answer2: {
      text: "answ2",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
  },

  {
    id: "3",
    question: "question3",
    answer1: {
      text: "answ1",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
    answer2: {
      text: "answ2",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
  },
];
```

How can you go through all the possible branches of the questionnaire and form such an object with data:

```js
  {
    branches: {
      questionsList: [
        [
          { "question1": "answ1" },
          { "question2": "answ1" },
        ],
        [
          { "question1": "answ1" },
          { "question2": "answ2" },
        ],
        [
          { "question1": "answ2" },
          { "question3": "answ1" },
        ],
          [
          { "question1": "answ2" },
          { "question3": "answ2" },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
```

Comment: Please don't use the JSON tag for JavaScript object literals. There is no JSON in your question.

Comment: Do you want to make the `quiz ` object from the `branches` object?

Comment: What happens in this path: `question 1 -> answer 2 -> question 3 -> answer 2 -> ???`. Should it now go to `question 4`? If so, then in `branches.questionsList` array the last element should be `[{"question1": "answ2"}, {"question3" : "answ2"}, {"question4" :"<<what goes here?>>"}]`

Comment: edited the question. No 4 questions yet

Comment: No, the branches object is formed from all possible question paths

Comment: What I think you may need here is a `Tree` structure. `q1` at the root. It has two children `a1`, `a2`. Now, `a1`  has one child `q2`, and `a2` has one child `q3`. Similarly `q2` has 2 children - same as `q3`. Now, traverse through this tree from root to all leaf nodes & that should give you the desired result. Will try to post an answer.

Comment: Is it possible to flexibly make a tree structure? Because there can be more than 2 branches from one question. And need the loop to count all possible variations and write them to the branches object.

Answer (score 0):

This may be one implementation to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getAllBranches = arr => {
  // first create a map/object to quickly access each question by id
  const qMap = arr.reduce((f, i) => ({
    ...f,
    [i.id]: {...i, ch: [ // keep track of 'children' using this 'ch' array
      ...Object.keys(i)
      .filter(k => k.includes('answer')) // any key with 'answer' is included
      .map(k => ({...i[k]}))
    ]}
  }), {});
  
  // recursive function to get the desired objective
  const recurGet = ({id, question, ch}) => (
    ch.map(({text, nextQuestion}) => (
      nextQuestion.length === 0 // if no 'nextQuestion', simply return an object
      ? { [question] : text }
      : recurGet(qMap[nextQuestion]).map(ob => ({
        [question]: text,
        ...ob // if else, recursive-call and append question-answer to each result
      }))
    ))
  );
  
  return recurGet(qMap[arr[0].id]);
};

const quiz = [{
    id: "1",
    question: "question1",
    answer1: {
      text: "answ1",
      nextQuestion: "2",
    },
    answer2: {
      text: "answ2",
      nextQuestion: "3",
    },
  },

  {
    id: "2",
    question: "question2",
    answer1: {
      text: "answ1",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
    answer2: {
      text: "answ2",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
  },

  {
    id: "3",
    question: "question3",
    answer1: {
      text: "answ1",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
    answer2: {
      text: "answ2",
      nextQuestion: "",
    },
  },
];

// add the branches into a new object to meet 
// the desired objective's structure
const resObj = {
  branches: {
    questionsList: getAllBranches(quiz)
  }
};
console.log(resObj);
```

**Explanation**

Relevant comments have been included in the code above.

Please post any questions on comments for further detailed explanation, if required.

**NOTE**: Please supply further test cases (such as with more than 2 answers, etc) to effectively test the solution.